# Wireless LAN worked in 14.04, doesn't on 16.04 even with the proprietary drivers

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, 16.04, broadcom

The problem is, that the proprietary drivers, that worked with 14.04, no longer work for Ubuntu 16.04. I did not upgrade, I did a clean installation.`sudo lshw -C network` shows that my WLAN card is UNCLAIMED, even though I'm using proprietary drivers, which solved the issue back in 14.04. I did a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04, I did not upgrade. I'm new to Ubuntu, and Linux, I have been using Windows all my life, so bare with me. It would be really helpful if I could finally stop using my phone as a wireless tether. Also I used a script that was mentioned in one post to help with the answer. Cheers

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 04 May 2016 19:49 CEST +0200

Booted last: 04 May 2016 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 27 Sep 2015 00:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:0864]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6645]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 06cb:2970 Synaptics, Inc. touchpad
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b469 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0502:3827 Acer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04ca:2009 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

acer_wmi               20480  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
cfg80211              565248  0
wmi                    20480  1 acer_wmi
video                  40960  1 acer_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp2s0f1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enxe29ea79c4d96 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr   
          inet addr:192.168.42.253  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e203:6a7d:868a:748c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1551 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1593 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:918949 (918.9 KB)  TX bytes:273825 (273.8 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enxe29ea79c4d96  no wireless extensions.

enp2s0f1  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.42.129  0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enxe29ea79c4d96
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enxe29ea79c4d96
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enxe29ea79c4d96

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       778     1  0 19:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enxe29ea79c4d96
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         MediaTek
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        T02
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/net/enxe29ea79c4d96
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enxe29ea79c4d96
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       5dd869a6-e315-4289-9761-2d898b466ea6
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   5dd869a6-e315-4289-9761-2d898b466ea6 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.253/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.253
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1462387551
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = Technomancer
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::e203:6a7d:868a:748c/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0f1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:02:00.1/net/enp2s0f1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Belgrade (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enxe29ea79c4d96  no frequency information.

enp2s0f1  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enxe29ea79c4d96  Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0f1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     00D8DA6D3B739DDD31FFF50
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

[   14.718416] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 enxe29ea79c4d96: renamed from usb0
[   30.518187] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enxe29ea79c4d96: link is not ready
[   30.526438] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0f1: link is not ready
[   30.605747] r8169 0000:02:00.1 enp2s0f1: link down
[   30.605842] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp2s0f1: link is not ready
[  161.825895] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[  161.825908] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770490/broadcom-wireless-drivers-unclaimed-after-installing-update-16-04).

1) Remove bcmwl-kernel-source
    `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
2) Re-install bcmwl-kernel-source
    `sudo apt-get update`
    `sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`
It will ask you for a password, if secure boot isn't turned off already.
After the reboot, it will ask you for a character from the password you entered previously, so you can turn off secure boot. Ubuntu will boot up, and voila.
And yes, a part of the problem was secure boot, like the previous answer stated. But the previous answer didn't work towards disabling secure boot.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I also updated my Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 LTS and faced similar issue. Following solution worked for me.

Open the terminal and Get the name of current system by

```
uname -r
4.4.0-21-generic
```

Then reinstall the linux image by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic
```

It will ask to set a password, enter a password. You will be required to enter this password on after reboot. Now reboot the system.

You will be asked to disable boot secure and after selecting yes, it will ask the password. Like

Enter password character 6:

Here you need to enter the 6th character of your password. Similarly follow these steps.

Now you should see All wifi networks available.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but wireless still isn't working. I wasn't asked to disable secure boot, and I wasn't asked for a password after the reboot.